# Counting different types of text and producing specific text outcome

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

So I'm trying to create a tracker where I can gauge a pass/warning/fail status for each category. Under "Report Status", I wanted a function that can put out the text "Fail" if one of the months has a "fail" tag or two "warning" tags, a "Warning" if there is only one "warning" tag, and then "pass" otherwise.

I've tried to scaffold my function as follows:

```
=(IF(E3:K3,"Fail"), "Fail", if(E3:K3,"Warning"),"Warning")
```

But I'm only getting errors.

I know this is probably a very easy code to do but I'm an absolute noob so I would appreciate any form of help!!

[image]

Comment: Also, Hello @sheetmypants! [Please do take the tour.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(
    OR(
        COUNTIF(E3:K3,"Fail") >= 1,
        COUNTIF(E3:K3,"Warning") >= 2
    ),
    "Fail",
    IF(
        COUNTIF(E3:K3,"Warning") = 1,
        "Warning",
        "Pass"
    )
)
```

This should do it. Nested IF's felt like the best choice for this since it's very specific.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome! Please do consider accepting my answer (by clicking the checkmark), this is to mark this question as resolved.